# iPhone 4 ignoring viewport meta tag

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, iphone-4, metatag

I have just added the following HTML to the `<head>` section of my iPhone web app:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>`

This (supposedly) limits the zoom of the page so the user can't zoom in.  On iOS versions prior to 4.0, this tag is respected - but iOS versions 4.0+ completely ignore it, and lets you zoom in all you want.  Furthermore, if you rotate, iPhone 4 will weirdly zoom in automatically.

So what I'm asking is, How can I "lock" the zoom for my app?
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone... can you give a link to the complete page? Problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @Eiko: Try http://welmel.us/boatfloat/scores.html This page has the above meta tag, but you can still zoom in.

Comment: What device, what OS, what browser? Works just fine with Safari on iPhone 4 and on iPad (both running 4.2).

Comment: iPhone 4, iOS 4.2.1, Safari — If you can zoom in by double tapping or using two fingers, it's not working correctly.

Comment: Same configuration here. I can't get the score page to break. Even rotation seems to work well. I refresh the page, try to zoom and it stays fixed just fine. Anything special on your part? Jailbreak?

Comment: Wow. That's so weird. I can even zoom in on my standard iPhone 4, but I can't on the simulator… huh?  Maybe time to email Steve. hahaha

Comment: Can you check http://www.shredderchess.com/iphone if this works for you? Shouldn't zoom as well.

Comment: Yep. I can zoom there on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Zoom enabled in the Accessibility settings (inside General), Safari seems to ignore the viewport meta (tested only on iPhone 4 on iOs 4).

You need to reload your page after changing the setting.

Comment: Wow - it works! - that's the craziest bug isn't it?!  Thank you so much for the answer!  I've looked everywhere for an explanation to the unexplained behavior on my iPhone, and now I see it was all the zoom's fault, who would have thought...

Comment: Well, actually I can see how that would make sense, because if you needed the Zoom feature you would probably want to zoom in on web pages to see text better.  But, even then, it could break entire websites!

Answer (score 1):

typo? use comma.

try this:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`

Also, why use maximum-scale if you want the viewport to be fixed?
If you use "width=device-width", the viewport will be different between iphone3 and iphone4.

You may try this one too:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width = (your page width), user-scalable = no"/>`

please replace (your page width) with your site's width.