# iPhone 4 issue with viewport

Tags: iphone, viewport

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891031/how-do-i-specify-image-size-so-it-scales-to-100-width-on-iphone-and-android-brow) and received an answer regarding sizing images for mobile browsers.

The answer provided works for inline images. However, I need to use background images as part of a header, as well. They're set via css classes. On android, they scale correctly in both portrait and landscape, but on iPhone they automatically zoom in when turning from portrait to landscape. This is a problem. I have a viewport tag set like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Apparently when the iPhone (at least the newest versions) are turned to landscape mode, it rescales and zooms in really huge, rather than just repeating the background more times to account for the wider screen.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<tr><td colspan="2" class="logoHeader"><img src="/images/mobile/logoCopy.png" /></td></tr>
```

where class logoHeader looks like this:

```
td.logoHeader {
  background: url(/images/mobile/transparentLeavesRight.png) top right no-repeat, 
            url(/images/mobile/transparentLeavesGradient.png) top left repeat-x;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Any ideas? I know that I can add the user-scalable property of the viewport meta, but we don't want to prevent users from manually zooming if necessary. We just want to prevent it from automatically zooming when the phone is turned into landscape mode.

FYI: I did search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272511/iphone-4-ignoring-viewport-meta-tag) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514114/ios-4-web-app-viewport-scaled-in-landscape), which are pretty much asking the same question. But they're both a number of months old, and neither has an actual answer to the problem, so I'm hoping that someone has come up with something in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid rescaling when orientation changes try

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=1024' />
```

and adjust width for your needs. If this won't work on android correctly, you can always send different viewport tag by PHP+user agent detection, or set it on device by javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Change the viewport to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale="selfrender"/>
```

Comment: I'm unable to find any documentation supporting "selfrender" as a valid value for initial-scale in the viewport meta tag. Can you show me where that's written?

Comment: That's not even valid markup.. content="width=device-width, initial-scale="selfrender" there's an extra quote inside the attribute's value